# OCI8 в OpenServer

Tags: php, openserver

Использую Open Server, необходимо подключить OCI8. Зашел в файл C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\userdata\config\PHP_5.5_php и раскомментировал:

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
```

Однако при просмотре phpinfo(), раздела OCI8 нет (dll в папке есть).

Comment: А сервер вы перезагружали после обновления конфигурации ?

Comment: Да перезагружал

Answer (score 0):

Раскомментировать надо через интерфейс (дополнительно->конфигурация->php). скачать с сайта oracle нужные dll и просто закинуть их в папку php/PHP_(версия)/ext и будет вам счастье

Comment: Этот вариант я уже опробовал

Comment: если править напрямую в файле то это перезатрется, нужено через интерфейс программы

Comment: Если вы про (дополнительно->конфигурация->php), то я так и делал

Comment: попробуйте вместо php_oci8.dll использовать php_oci8_12c.dll и к ней надо oci.dll

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: ну смотрите, у меня стоит в конфиге `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll` и в папке modules\php\PHP_(ВЕРСИЯ)\ext лежат: php_oci8_12c.dll, oci.dll, ocijdbc12.dll, oci32.dll, oramysql12.dll, oraocci12.dll,  oraocci12d.dll, orasql12.dll запускается на любом компьютере и работает прекрасно

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо - метод скопировать в папку все dll из oracle/BIN/ помогли.
Хоть и не самое изящное решение - но работает и хорошо.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).